# breezejs EntityQuery fail

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, breeze

I'm playing around with the breezejs knockout Todo-list tutorial/template
(http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeknockout-template).
I decided to make a new Employees class and see if I could bind to a list of employees.

The view references a variable in the VM 'results' which is supposed to be an observable array of employees.

```
<section data-bind="foreach: results">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <form>                            
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" />
                    </form>
                </header>                    
            </article>
        </section>
```

In the viewmodel I added the result var and a line in order to automatically load employees into the results variable.

```
/* Defines the Todo application ViewModel */
window.todoApp.todoListViewModel = (function (ko, datacontext) {
var results = ko.observableArray();
var todoLists = ko.observableArray(),        
    error = ko.observable(),    
    viewmodel = {
        showTestPage: showTestPage,
        results: results,
        todoLists: todoLists,
        error: error,
        addTodoList: addTodoList,
        deleteTodoList: deleteTodoList,
        clearErrorMessage: clearErrorMessage,
        searchTerms: ko.observable(""),
        performSearch: performSearch            
    };   

// load todoLists immediately    
datacontext.getTodoLists(todoLists, error);
// load employees
datacontext.getEmployees(results, error);
 return viewmodel;
```

Here is my datacontext function

```
function getEmployees(empObservable, errorObservable)
{        
    return breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Employees")            
        .where('lastName', 'startsWith', 'G')
        .orderBy("lastName")
        .using(manager).execute()
        .then(getSucceeded)
        .fail(getFailed);

    function getSucceeded(data) {
        empObservable(data.results);
    }
    function getFailed(error) {
        errorObservable("This is broke *BREAK*" + error.message + "*BREAK*");
    }
}
```

The fail occurs and the error.message I see includes the data that I should be getting in my results. It's even ordered and filtered correctly, though I'm only showing one record below as an example.  I don't get any other error messages.

```
This is broke *BREAK*[{"$id":"1","$type":"ToDoBreeze.Models.Employee, ToDoBreeze","ID":"12345","LastName":"Gaston","FirstName":"Jake"}]*BREAK*
```

I don't suppose anyone else messing around with this template has had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to find the right words for this question to come up, but it looks like this is the answer.  I guess I'll leave mine up in case someone else finds it.
([Query failed and the error.message is the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780735/query-failed-and-the-error-message-is-the-data))

Basically, I had something in my employee initializer in the model that should not have been there.